Why would my male soldiers not use steroids?
I have a medieval country comprised entirely of women warring against another country. To compensate for their lacking physical strength, the woman nation uses anachronistic steroids on their soldiers.
On the other hand, the other nation has a typical all-male army. Unlike the woman nation, they don't use the steroids on their soldiers.
For certain reasons, both nations want to constantly invade each other. Assume they both have the manufacturing info and needed infrastructure for the steroids.
For the female soldiers, the use of the steroids is an obvious boon. It gives them a chance of reducing the gap of physical strength against their male enemies.
For the male soldiers, the steroids would have a greater effect on them compared to the women. Using it would cut out a potential advantage of their female enemies and emphasize their own advantage.
So why would the male army not use steroids in their wars?

The answer to any why would people do x question is far too broad for this site. We're here to help you build your world, but brainstorming and generating ideas is not the sort of question that is permitted on this site.

VTC:Opinion-Based. This is why we don't host questions about the decisions made by characters or organizations. You need to frame questions like this in the context of your world, not your story. Right now it's in the context of your story: that means an infinite number of equally-valid reasons (side-effects, cost-of-manufacture, too valuable for general field use, religiously immoral, and so many more). Remember, this is the wrong kind of brainstorming and it's prohibited.

1st Anabolic Steroids (which I assume is the one you are thinking of cuz it increases muscle mass/muscle performance, and aggression). are testosterone. So lets get that out of the way. It is the 'male' hormone (Women also have it, just significantly lower levels).

For the male soldiers, the steroids would have a greater effect on them compared to the women. Using it would cut out a potential advantage of their female enemies and emphasize their own advantage.

Says who?
A steroid dose that doubles the amount of testosterone in a women would increase the amount testosterone in a man by 5%. That is an increase, but not a significant one. I think a man who thought that he had just ingested magic performance enhancing sugar would get more of a performance boost than he would get from that small of a dosage. I could be wrong, not an expert.
Unless your matriarchal society has been dosing their soldiers since birth (unlikely as in a medieval country the vast majority of soldiers are conscripts) these female soldiers will have had steroids enhancing their performance for what 6 months, maybe a year? (Medieval conscriptions didn't last a long time.) While the male solders they are facing will have been effectively on steroids (compared to the women) since birth.
This is why 16 year old males who are training in a sport are regularly faster and stronger than female Olympians in that same sport.
Its why a 15 year old male soccer players beat the best female soccer team in the world 5 - 2.
Compared to women, men are on an extremely high steroid dosage. And have been since birth.
Okay, so you have female super soldiers who have been dosed since birth Making them the equal to a man... Higher than that and the risk of heart failure, kidney failure, and/or liver failure which would leave you with very few super soldiers. These soldiers will most likely be infertile. While the patriarchies super solder equivalent are knights who pass their title to their descendants, I don't see them choosing infertility and dooming their line to extinction, which explains why the knights don't dose.
The normal female soldier conscripts are weaker then your male conscripts but not as much as they normally would be.

Testosterone is a steroid
Testosterone is a steroid. (Specifically, an anabolic steroid, the kind of steroid which enhances physical performance and muscle mass.) Men are effectively on steroids from age seven. They don't need more steroids. And whatever puny amount of steroids the women get it will never even approach the effect of one or two decades of massive amounts of testosterone raging in the blood of a man in his twenties.
Fun fact #1: The anabolic steroids some dishonest athletes take work exactly by mimicking the effects of testosterone...
Fun fact #2: Taking extra steroids helps a little, but it won't transform a knowledge worker into an athlete. Steroids may help the third best Olympic athlete beat the second best Olympic athlete, but they won't help the best female Olympic athlete run faster than a 16 years old high-school boy who won the county championship. Because at 16 years of age the boy has been on massive doses of natural steroids for nine years already.

Yeah, women have like 6% the natural amount of testosterone that men have. And a doses of 100-200 mg a week is enough to bring a man from low T (which is still 3X women at highest natural level) to the mid range .

Fertility (or the lack thereof)
Anachronistic steroids that raise androgen above normal levels can cause infertility in both males and females. It's unclear how reproduction works in your all female society, but I'm going to assume you have some sort of explanation. To maintain a similar rate of reproduction to their mixed gender counterparts, roughly half the population needs to be able to bear children, meaning the other half can effectively trade their fertility for increased physical strength without major societal repercussions. In a mixed gender society, the male half is critical for reproduction so making them all infertile is simply not a valid option.
Limited Knowledge/Availability
In the real world, synthetic androgens were first invented in the 1930s, so discovery in a fantasy medieval setting, while possible with proper motivation and a bit of scientific hand waving, would be quite advanced for its time and likely to be unknown or at least misunderstood by other societies. As you explained, this all female society has sufficient reason to invest in study and research of these performance enhancing substances as well as incentive to keep their research and discoveries to themselves.
Reasonable Alternative Explanations
While performance enhancers can increase overall strength, they cannot make you super human. The opposition is more likely to think "wow, these ladies are buff! They must work out a LOT!", and not "these ladies are way stronger than they otherwise should be! They must be taking performance enhancing drugs!"
Think of it this way: the edge that modern athletes get when using performance enhancers is slight enough that it can only be reliably determined with drug tests, so there is absolutely no way that the opposition in your world could accurately determine the use of drugs or even (as mentioned above) that such things exist in the first place.
Why use it at all?
Raw physical strength is among the less important aspects of an effective military force. Field tactics, communication and morale, among other things, all contribute more to a military's success than just being really strong. Furthermore, the potential negative side effects of taking artificial hormones (heart attack, stroke, liver or kidney failure, high blood pressure, blood clots, fluid retention, high cholesterol, mood swings, paranoia, manic behavior, hallucinations, delusions) would almost certainly make using them do way more harm than good, especially in the field on a military campaign where medical intervention in the event of an acute reaction is limited.
All things considered, an all female military that trains just as hard as, or possibly harder than their overconfident male opposition will not have nearly as much of a disadvantage as you seem to think, if they have any at all. In fact, the opposition thinking they have an advantage because they are male might actually serve the female army quite well.
I get the feeling that the use of performance enhancers stemmed from the thought that an all female military couldn't possibly stand any chance against an all male army without them, and this simply isn't true. If use of the drugs is somehow central to the story, then it is what it is. Otherwise, just cut it out and tell your story, letting the women be powerful on their own.

I think you're seriously underestimating the impact of physical strength on a medieval battlefield before firearms. There's a reason effective female warriors are a rather rare exception. One very obvious and simple example is that your male longbowmen easily outrange the females, but this applies across the battlefield.

@WillRoss1 I think that you have never done any type of martial arts. Yes technique helps someone deal with a strength advantage. But its hard and it takes a lot of skill to overcome a little advantage. If both sides have similar levels of training? Stronger dudes are going to win.

Pride (and fertility)
Do you want to boast at your buddies you needed to take performance enhancing drugs to beat a woman? Even if you did need it, of course you wont. Your male macho culture does not accept that, so you rather die than win on drugs instead of your own physical prowess.
There is also a problem that too much can seriously damage many other parts of the body. Testicles can shrivel to infertility for example. With further medieval superstition it can be avoided like the literal plague. Other side-effects recently found are brain damage/shrinking. So big negative effects connected to a drug that can harm masculine culture would drive people away. I mean being an essential eunuch with a penis still makes you lesser in most masculine cultures.

Religion
For a medieval level culture, religion is often a very strong factor, and if the religion of your male-soldier culture forbids "performance enhancing drugs" that could be all it takes to stigmatize their use.  That won't completely eliminate it, of course (just as religious bans on, for instance, alcohol don't completely eliminate drinking) -- but it makes it easier for more devout comrades to spot and call out an illicit PED user.
Additionally, the religious factor would allow the male-soldier culture to make this a holy war -- those evil women use these forbidden substances, thinking that will let them destroy our way of life!

It's always popular here, but I feel like using religion as the answer for everything is a bit of a cheap copout. If there's a strong practical reason to do something, especially when it comes to something as important is warfare, then unless your religion has a strong army of its own behind it, its rules are going to be quietly or not so quietly ignored.

@user111403 Well then, perhaps the holy war isn't just against the outsider women, but against those who make, distribute, and use the "forbidden fruit" within the homeland.

That's definitely a possible scenario, but it just shifts the question rather than answering, because now you need to explain why the Church is not just opposed to steroids, but so strongly opposed that it's worth fighting over. This is my problem with the "religion" answer. It's usually presented as "religion, no need to explain anything", but in fact religious requirements almost always exist for a reason.

And that reason (based on Earthly religions, anyway) always seems to boil down to control of the congregation or the entire civilization.  I'll think about adding to this answer when I have some time (in a few hours).

It's Witchcraft!
This all-woman country is setting itself up for trouble.  They must be deal with evil spirits or ghosts for their women to be able to act like men.  Every flood, famine, storm, or pestilence in this country is attributed to this use of potions from witches.
Any man who took their potions is obviously trying to bring down trouble on his own country.  This becomes even more clear when such men start showing such traits as developing breasts.

This is probably the only valid answer since steroids as a concept were only discovered in the 1930s. You could pull that back to the late 1880s when Charles-Édouard Brown-Séquard started experimenting with testicular fluid (without having any idea what a "steroid" was). But "medieval" is 450-1450. Yup, witchcraft and potions.

Well among other things it will run their blood sugar levels sky high.
Steroids and growth hormones have lots of side effects. So choosing to do this comes with a lot of problems. There's a reason you don't see even modern day militaries doing this.
There's also the fact that winning a military fight rarely comes down to who has the bigger people. I'll put money on a disciplined group of 12 year old girls against a group of undisciplined Hulk Hogan wannabes any day.
There's also the fact that most men already get plenty of testosterone. Once you have plenty, more isn't always a good thing.
Seriously, spend your money on training and drilling. Save Captain Americas super soldier serum for the comics.

This doesn't seem like a question that would have just one answer. Rather, I think there are a few components that, while individually not very strong, come together to present a reasonable explanation:
Culture
Another answer has already mentioned this one, but I'd like to add a little on top of it. Of course, there's male pride, but given that this is a medieval society, you could very reasonably also insert a religious/moral taboo that considers these steroids "evil magic" or something equivalent. It's better if your explanation exploits both the negative(arrogance) and positive(righteousness) aspects of the male soldiers' behavior, so that you can reasonably explain why all soldiers avoid the steroids, rather than just the prideful ones or the righteous ones.
Cost
Steroids are expensive. I'm guessing that the dynamics of the all-female nation(queendom?) are a little more military-oriented than the regular nation, since the latter is the more natural organization for humans, so in the regular nation, there are other things that require money and are not related to war, so their military probably receives a smaller % of the nation's budget, and therefore they can't afford to juice every single soldier up.
Necessity
The physical differences between men and women are extremely pronounced. The female army uses steroids because they NEED to use it. It's just not feasible for an all-woman force to face an all-man force with medieval equipment without "leveling the playing field", so to speak. The male army, on the other hand, does not need to enhance itself, they already have natural physical superiority(or at least they think so), and, therefore, steroids aren't really necessary
Consequences
This one ties up all the previous ones pretty neatly, I think. The female nation probably doesn't rely on sexual reproduction for population maintenance, but the regular nation does. Steroids affect your fertility, and in a society that relies on fertility to keep existing, there is most likely a taboo against that (We certainly do have this taboo in our society, which relies on fertility). Spending money on steroids means not having money for public infrastructure, or for better swords and armor, or for other forms of alchemy that can be useful for the nation, so the negative consequences of investing in steroids might not seem like they are worth it if it isn't absolutely necessary to do so.
Misinformation/Fantastical restrictions
I think all of the previous 4 are good regular explanations for the phenomenon you described. You could also go with a fantastical explanation and say that the anachronistic steroid only works on women. This doesn't even need to be true, the male nation only has to believe it is(And certainly the female nation would be interested in running disinformation campaigns so that their adversaries don't use the steroids and negate the advantage)
Hope this helps!

The human body doesn't make muscle tissue out of synthetic Androgens, it makes it out of food, calories, protein.  Does the otherwise medieval society also have a vast supply of isolated whey protein?  If everything else about the technology is medieval level, it is entirely plausible that the other nation is simply incapable of producing enough food for any meaningfully large number of soldiers to get bigger and stronger with the assistance of exogenous compounds than they otherwise could.
Raising the testosterone level of an individual with a female hormone balance will encourage their body to invest the available nutrition in more traditionally male traits.  That does not mean people who already have normally male testosterone levels have access to additional nutrition to take advantage of further elevated levels.
